# How can I easily explain interference to a tour group?

Tags: education, interference, interferometry

I'm looking for unique and illustrative ways to explain the phenomenon of interference to a tour group consisting of all types of people, from elementary school kids to adults.  I run into this problem from time to time at the [LIGO Livingston Observatory](http://www.ligo-la.caltech.edu/).  I often use my hands to illustrate two waves adding up constructively or destructively, but I don't think it gets across to people who aren't already familiar with the idea.

I have the possibility to use small gadgets or home-made devices, but they can't be too complex or bulky.

Comment: What about YDSE?

Comment: This is not an engineering question.  I'm not asking how to build a device, I want good ideas for **explaining** the **principle** to a layman.  Neither is it an educational question; one needs to have a deep understanding of the concept to come up with intuitive and simple ways of illustrating it. Please don't close this question.

Comment: Various makers of classroom demo equipment make little ripple tanks explicitly for this kind of thing.

Comment: @dmckee I appreciate your comment and the answer below, but I was really more interested in good ways of explaining in words to a layperson the idea of interference.  Demonstrations are of course best, but the situation in which I run into this problem doesn't allow for demonstrations larger than can be held in my hand.

Comment: @ChrisMueller I was worried about that having lead tours around microBooNE once or twice myself, but we had a corner in the "common" room where something could be setup for a day if you knew the tour was coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interference of sound waves might work for you.

One experiment that comes to mind is to have two speakers playing identical periodic sounds. (I don't think they have to be pure sinusoidals, but "simple" so it sounds like a note.) Depending on where you stand relative to the speakers, you'll hear "dull" areas where the sound isn't loud, demonstrating deconstructive interference. Depending on the patience of your group, you could even have them walk around and map out the destructive areas. (I actually think mapping it out would be quite hard; test it before doing it.) The number of destructive areas and their areas can be adjusted by tuning the frequencies of your source and/or the speaker separation.

There's a [PhET simulation here.](http://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/sound)

Comment: If you do this, have the visitors cover one ear! I found a description of an experimental apparatus that does just this [at this website.](https://sharepoint.washington.edu/phys/facilities/lectdemos/Pages/Oscillations-and-Waves.aspx#3B). Look at 3B55.